# How to use my files to create Docker image?

Tags: python, git, docker

Im using a framework that runs on Docker. They have given me a dockerfile but now I have made changes to the project and I want to build those files instead. I thought only editing those files and running the same dockerfile should do but I guess not. For some reason, the framework is copying its git content in the dockerfile first. Does this means that theyre getting their data from git all the time to create the image instead of compiling the files in the folder? If so, how can I edit the dockerfile to compile my files ?
This is the clone file from the dockerfile :

```
RUN git clone https://github.com/abc/abc.git /root/abc
RUN pip --no-cache-dir install -r /root/abc/requirements.txt --process-dependency-links

WORKDIR /root/abc
CMD (tensorboard --logdir=data/tensorboard 2>data/tensorboard/err.log &); \
    /bin/bash
```

Comment: copy whatever in abc.git to /root/abc use copy command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If they have `RUN git clone` within the Dockerfile, you can do a few things.

For testing, fork the repository and place your fork within the Dockerfile.

For permanent changes, open a pull request to the repository.

Or, clone the repository, create a Dockerfile and copy all the content from the clone; example:

```
FROM python:latest

COPY ./ .

RUN pip --no-cache-dir install \
     -r /root/abc/requirements.txt \
     --process-dependency-links

WORKDIR /root/abc
```